# Openbox theme installation

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, themes, customization, openbox

I've downloaded an openbox theme (Shikiwise, Openbox 3.0) for my lubuntu desktop. I've copied it to `/usr/share/themes` and to `/home/username/.themes` and changed all the permissions to 'Anyone'.

For some reason in 'Customise Look and Feel' it only shows up under the Window Border tab, which looks great, but NOT under the Widget tab. I've noticed that there are other themes in `/usr/share/themes` which also don't show up.

Also when I start 'Openbox Configuration Manager' the theme is listed and i can highlight it, but there seems to be no way to install it. The 'OK' button just goes down the directory list, and right clicking doesn't bring up any options.

Really stuck here, so any help appreciated.

Comment: Re. "For some reason in 'Customise Look and Feel' it only shows up under the Window Border tab, which looks great, but NOT under the Widget tab.", that is perfectly fine. Openbox themes relate only to the window borders (and to the title bar and the min/max/close buttons). Under the Widget tab, you'll see gtk themes.

Comment: As for "Also when I start 'Openbox Configuration Manager' the theme is listed and i can highlight it, but there seems to be no way to install it.", that's all you need to do: just highlight any of the listed themes and then close the window. If the theme you've chosen is sufficiently visibly different from the previous one, you'll see the difference. You don't need to "install" it. In your theme folder you should see the named theme folder and inside that there should an `openbox-3` folder with files such as `themerc` and some other (.xbm) files.

Comment: Okay, I'll download the GTK theme for the windows. Think it's a bit odd to not have an 'install' button in OCM, but maybe it's just me... So, just one final issue: why do some themes under /usr/share/themes not show up under 'Customize Look and Feel' Widget tab, including some that have shown up in the past? Is it because they're not GTK?

Comment: Open their folders and look inside. If there aren't subfolders for `gtk-2.0` and `gtk-3.0`, they obviously won't show up.